# error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseInstanceIdService in IONIC 1 with plugin cordova-plugin-fcm

Tags: ionic-framework

My app is in ionic 1 and I am using cordova-plugin-fcm. Now when I am making build I am seeing this error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseInstanceIdService.

I know that google removed that library and I tried few solutions like 
Changing the android project.properties from:

cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+

To
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8 cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0

Few blogs are saying that there is another plugin which solved this issue but anyhow is there any solution for this plugin. If there is no way to solve in this plugin what should be right solution for andother plugin cordova-firebase-plugin. If you can provide any link that is very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. cordova-plugin-fcm seems to be no more supported. But a programmer forked it on github to correct recent problems. It's a new plugin but with the same features of cordova-plugin-fcm. So you can consider it the same plugin.

You can find it at 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-ng

From CLI it was sufficient to do the following commands:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-fcm
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-ng
```

And all returns to function correctly, at least for me :)